# SVG - circle rotating around circle

Tags: css, animation, svg

I have two circles, one just an outline, and one filled in.

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black">
  <circle stroke="black" stroke-width="1" r="100" cx="150" cy="150" fill="white"></circle>
  <circle r="10" cx ="50" cy="150"></circle>
</svg>
```

I want the filled-in circle to rotate around the other circle. How can I do this? A css/svg only solution would be great, as this will be a `.svg` file, not a `.html` file.

Comment: Please check this [question: How can I make a SVG element to move on the path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68883315/how-can-i-make-a-svg-element-to-move-on-the-path). You will also find examples on MDN line [<animateMotion>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion) or [css: offset-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/offset-path)

Comment: They work, but I am using circles, not paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a svg `SMIL` animation like [`<animateTransform>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateTransform)

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black">
  <circle stroke="black" stroke-width="1" r="100" cx="150" cy="150" fill="white" />
  <circle id="dot" r="10" cx="50" cy="150" />
      <animateTransform href="#dot" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 150 150" to="360 150 150" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</svg>
```

The above `<animateTransform>` values translates to these transformation attributes:

From

```
transform="rotate(0 150 150)"
```

to

```
transform="rotate(360 150 150)"
```

Unlike its css counterpart svg's rotate() accepts 3 arguments

1. rotation angle (mandatory)
2. transform origin x
3. transform origin y

This way we can define the pivot point – in this case the center of our circle/svg.

Probably the main benefit of SMIL animations: they will also play in `<img>` elements and background-images.
This concept is often used for loading spinner svgs.

Comment: Could you explain the code?

Answer (score 1):

So, I decided to try using only HTML and CSS for this.

```css
.inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.outter {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 115px;
  left: 115px;
  animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(125px);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translate(125px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <div class="outter"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.
Regards

EDITED: Made with SVG.

```css
.outter {
    transform-origin: 150px 150px;
    animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes spin {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black">
  <circle stroke="black" stroke-width="1" r="100" cx="150" cy="150" fill="white"></circle>
  <circle class="outter" r="10" cx ="50" cy="150"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: It works! the only issue though is that I am making a .svg file, not an html file.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for that. I edited my answer and made it with SVG.